# Xcode 6 Beta 4 archive build error unimplemented IR generation feature bitcast between types of different size

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, xcode6

I have a project I'm building with swift and Xcode 6 Beta 4. Trying to do a release build archive. When I build with release configuration I get the following error:

```
<unknown>:0: error: unimplemented IR generation feature bitcast between types of different size
```

Any clues on this? Seems to only happen when Selecting `Product > Archive` on the same scheme building `cmd-B` causes no issues and it builds successfully. I'm also able to Run the project in the ios simulator and on device with debug configurations.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

"Unimplemented IR generation feature" sounds like it's running into something in the compiler that hasn't been written yet. Seems to be an issue with the -Ofast setting for the Swift compiler; change your Release setting of Swift Compiler - Code Generation > Optimization Level to "None [-Onone]".

[image]

Comment: Here's hoping for next beta.

Comment: Still an issue in Beta 5. You deserve a hug.

Comment: Looks like it may be fixed in beta 6? Certainly I just turned optimisation back on and successfully built for release on a project that previously had this issue.

Comment: This issue is still exist in XCode6 GM. But your trick works!